# update a column by subtracting a variable

Tags: php, sql

the sql query doesn't seem to work ... where am I wrong?

```
$barcode = $_GET['barcode_from_index2'];
$amountofsales = $_GET['amount_of_sales'];

if($amountofsales < 1)
{
echo "quantity must be greater than zero";    
}

else{
$sql = "UPDATE inventary SET quantities_left='quantities_left - $amountofsales' WHERE Cod_product='$barcode'";
```

Comment: `'quantities_left - $amountofsales'` Why make this a string?

Answer (score 0):

If you paste that statement in phpMyAdmin for example, you'll notice that `$amountofsales` and `$barcode` are NOT SQL variables.

They are only accesible inside your PHP Script.

Also, you are using a string in `quantities_left='quantities_left - $amountofsales'` and `Cod_product='$barcode'`. Why?

You have to:

```php
$sql = "UPDATE inventary SET quantities_left=quantities_left - {$amountofsales} WHERE Cod_product='{$barcode}'";
```

or

```php
$sql = "UPDATE inventary SET quantities_left=quantities_left - " . $amountofsales . " WHERE Cod_product='" . $barcode} . "'";
```

Note that I left `Cod_product` as a string because I don't know what type it should be.